# How to Create a Simple Related Posts Plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I think it would be best to keep some things in a plugin. I have this code:

```
<div class="related-posts">

<h3>Related posts</h3>

<?php
    $orig_post = $post;
    global $post;
    $tags = wp_get_post_tags($post->ID);

    if ($tags) {
    $tag_ids = array();
    foreach($tags as $individual_tag) $tag_ids[] = $individual_tag->term_id;
    $args=array(
        'tag__in' => $tag_ids,
        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID),
        'posts_per_page'=>4, // Number of related posts to display.
        'caller_get_posts'=>1
    );

    $my_query = new wp_query( $args );

    while( $my_query->have_posts() ) {
    $my_query->the_post();
    ?>

    <div class="relatedthumb">
        <a rel="external" href="<? the_permalink()?>"><?php the_post_thumbnail(array(150,100)); ?><br />
        <?php the_title(); ?>
        </a>
    </div>

    <? }
    }
    $post = $orig_post;
    wp_reset_query();
?>
</div>
```

But I am not sure how to add it to a plugin. My main problem is I am not sure how to call this in my single.php...I know to add the class and function in the plugin and the basic setup, but other than that any advice is helpful :)

Comment: Put it in a class in the main file of the plugin, that class will be available in single.php if the plugin is activated.

Comment: Yes but I am not sure how to call it in single.php :D

Comment: do you want to call it dynamically on single.php (single post page) file, you want to put the class/function name on the single.php ?

Comment: Whatever is the recommended way. I am looking to learn best practices :)

Comment: FWIW, there are some good related posts plugins already out there. I would definitely advise some sort of caching/transients/calculating relations at save to avoid heavy resource usage. If you are the same Jagst3r15 from the old Thematic forums, hi there!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code looks ok at a brief scan of the code. What you need is a plugin header comment, some way to wrap it up and prepare it for output and a way to call it in your templates.

1. Plugin comment: The minimum thing you need is `/* Plugin Name: Your plugins Name */`
2. Wrap your plugin in a function and add it a filter

   ```
   add_filter( 'your-filter-name', 'pluginCallback' );
   function pluginCallback()
   {
       // Your code without any echo or direct HTML tag calls *)
   }
   ```
3. Then add it to your template:

   ```
   echo apply_filters( 'your-filter-name', "" );
   ```

***)** Instead of adding `<div>` HTML output directly, or echo DOM nodes (for e.g. `echo '<div>';`), simply put them into a string and return the result:

```
$html = "";
if ( $query->have_posts()  )
{
    while ( $query->have_posts() )
    {
        $query->the_post();

        $html .= '<div class="relatedthumb">';
        $html .= sprintf( '<a href="%s" title="%s">%s</a>',
            get_the_permalink(),
            get_the_title(),
            get_the_post_thumbnail( /* args */ )
        );
        $html .= '</div>';
    }
}
// ... etc.
return $html;
```

Comment: hi I am not sure what you mean by no direct HTML tag calls....don't I need html for structure?

Comment: See edit of the answer.